# Fixing corrupted cmd.exe

Tags: cmd.exe

for some reason still unclear to me, my cmd.exe seems to be completely broken. I can't start it, regardless how I try it. VS Code returns a Error Code 1 when it starts to open it as a new terminal. Starting it from system32 directly without any shortcuts also doesn't work, I get no reply at all.

Switching users fixes it, restarting in safe mode does not. Running a system repair (update in-place) via the media creation tool also doesn't help.

Is there a known fix for this? I assume there is something wrong with the account but I really don't want to switch accounts. When you tend to work with quite a bit of software, that's always more trouble than one would think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broken cmd.exe

> Switching users fixes it, restarting in safe mode does not. Running a
> system repair (update in-place) via the media creation tool also
> doesn't help.

You have a corrupted user profile. Running a Repair Install will not repair that.

You must make a new User Profile.

(a) Log in as yourself. Make a good copy in a secure (non-User) location and back up all documents, data and email, and also favorites if you have many favorites.

(b) Assuming this current but damage User is a member of Administrators, make a new Windows User Account and make it a member of Administrators.

(c) Log in as the new administrator account. Go to Advanced System settings and make a copy of the damaged profile. Locate the profile backup in the same folder as you established for your data.

(d) Now I assume you want the new User to have the same name as the damaged one.  So then you now need to delete the damaged profile. Be certain you have all your backups.

(e) Delete the user id of the damaged profile and then make a new user with the same name. Make this a member of Administrators.

(f) Log in as the new user, and set it up. Most apps will need to be run under the new user.

You may wish to thoroughly review the steps a couple of times.

Once you are ready, start in and create the new User and Profile.

Good Luck with this.